# Joomla Smart search limit displayed results per pagination

Tags: joomla-3.x, t3-framework

Currently my Smart search module is showing 100 results per pagination. Where can I set that only 10 results will be shown per pagination. I searched for this setting in module and general configuration, but i cannot find it.

Is it maybe hardcoded somewhere?

I am using Joomla 3.4.5.

Answer (score -1):

In the file `JoomlaFolder\libraries\cms\pagination\pagination.php`

Look at `$dsplaypages = 10;` Line no :- 144 and change it to what ever you want.

Comment: That's a core override and not recommended.

Comment: Better yet override the pagination and then make the changes. Protostar does this